# I deleted the LDF file from my database

Tags: sql-server

By mistake, I deleted the LDF file from my database.

1 - I stopped the MSSQL.
2 - Deleted the file.
3 - Started the MSSQL again.

And BOOM, everything is missing.

I have a copy of the deleted LDF file.

If I just put it back in the folder, will my database be back to life?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to [*re-attach* the MDF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5946183/2864740) (it should create a new LDF as required); "everything is missing" is odd though, assuming the database is connected to, as the MDF stores the data, the LDF is just the transaction log.

Comment: Yes, it's odd, but when I click in the plus icon of my database tree, it does not display anything below.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to reattach database that will create new transaction log.

1. Detach/ Drop the database if exist.
2. Right click on the Databases Tab
3. Click Attach
4. Find the path
5. IMP- Where it showing the LOG path(Database details), it picks up default.
6. Simply Select the LOG location option and remove it.

alternative you can do it with t-sql to drop and attach

```
DROP DATABASE database_name
exec sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'database_name', @physname = 'D:\PathTo.mdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = '<your_DB_name>',
            @physname = '<full_path_to_mdf_file>'
```

Comment: To recover the LDF file I should attach it to the MDF? Even if I still have a copy of the deleted LDF?

Comment: @Gilbert If your copy is not old you can copy back it to its original location then try detach/attach your DB.