# Space utilization is huge when database backup file is restored in another PC

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to restore backup file(.bak) to my Sql Server, .bak file size is 40 MB. But after restoration to Sql Server 2012, it occupies 100 to 120 GB space in C drive. How to fix this?

(OS and SQL installed in C: drive)

Comment: How big is the data file and how big the log file? How much space is actually used by both files?

Comment: If you make your .bak file yourself, you can try to shrink the original database and then make the backup. If you have space enough, you can also shrink the database after restore. Additionally, you can store the database on a different drive.

Comment: In case you are not sure how to shrink: 
Right click your database in the SSMS -> Tasks -> Shrink -> Files

Comment: Hi @JodyT 
after restoring .ldf is 100 GB and .mdf is 40 MB.

when I receive .bak file, it was 40mb.

Comment: Hi @HoneyBadger
After DB shrink, there was only 12 GB reduce in disk space usage.

So, in total it takes 108 GB.
The actual .bak size is 40 MB.

Comment: Hi @Eric

Thanks for the trick. :)

Shrinked it but it only released 12 GB.

How come a .bak file of size 40 MB utilize the space of 100 to 120 GB !
I have no words to express my feeling ...

Comment: Don't just shrink the database on a production system.

Comment: @JodyT how else is he supposed to release the 99.9% unused space he has?

Comment: @usr I'm not saying you should never shrink a file. But telling a person to just go ahead and shrink some files without knowing the effects or even why the file is so big in the first place doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the perfect answer, but is one of the best solutions for my problem.

after taking .bak file, restore it with "restore with non-recovery mode", stop the SQL service, delete the .ldf file, re-start service, re-boot system.

This helped me empty the disk space of 100 GB(.ldf = 100 GB)

The answers which helped me resolve this are ...

[Why do we need the LDF files along with MDF files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946153/why-do-we-need-the-ldf-files-along-with-mdf-files) on stackoverflow

and my seniors suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @usr for helping me

Answer (score 1):

The restored database is as big as the database the backup was taken on. Reduce the size before taking the backup or reduce the size after restoring.

Comment: Hello @usr

Even after shrinking, it's only releasing 12 GB ...

It consumes 102 GB now...
Any more ideas please...

Comment: How to shrink a database is a standard process. Use a search engine to find out.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server won't backup empty space in your database files. If you have a log file that is 100GB large but it's empty then if won't take any space in your backup file.

If you restore the backup the files will be restored to there original size. The log file will be 100 GB again.

The same thing goes for the data files.

EDIT:

If you have a log file of 100 GB while your data is only 40 MB then something might be configured wrong. Is the database is full recovery without making any transaction log backups?

Comment: So, How do I resolve that...

It's a big issue for me ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can permit to lose data between full backups then set the database recovery mode to SIMPLE. If you can only lose a certain amount of data then set up a transaction log backup job. After doing that shrink the log file to 0 then grow it to the required size.

Comment: Thanks @JodyT ...
But is there any other way to reduce size ?
I need whole of the data (110 tables with 15 to 30 records in each).

Comment: Changing the recovery model or shrinking the log file does not make you lose any data. Your tables and records will stay intact. You can read more about the transaction log file [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190925.aspx).

Comment: the recovery mode is set to SIMPLE and the textarea is locked.

will try transaction log file.

If more help is required, I will definitely come back again.

If solved... will post the solution...
Thanks...